# Azure SQL Secondary read only copy

Tags: azure-sql-database

We want to have secondary read only database for Analytics,Reporting, Monitoring, and exposing to another application. Since we are using Azure DB, DTU is increasing because of these reads. So I want to have secondary database(Read scale out), so that I can share this secondary DB credential to them, so that it will not have any impact on primary database. So Please help me to setup the secondary database(Read scale out) in Azure. I have heard about geo replication, but it is only for certain region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capability to use a local readable secondary is in preview.  It will work on larger reservation sizes (premium and up, though perhaps some of the standards will work). This is not limited to certain regions today.

Active geo dr can also be used to do reads scale out (but please note that it costs money for the dr copy since it gives you disaster recovery not just read scale out).

Instructions for both can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-read-scale-out

Intra-db resource governance would be the other way to split mixed workloads.  However, this feature does not currently exist in sql azure (though it is a roadmap item).

Comment: cunningham,  How to enable that using T-SQL?

Comment: The mechanism is not "within a database" so it's not really something to enable via T-SQL.  You need to use the REST API or powershell commandlets (which internally call the REST API).

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT geo replication requires you to setup your replica server in a different region, so it would increase latency a little bit right?  Can you confirm this is in premium and up instances and not available in vcore or standard?

Comment: Active Geo DR can be used to set up a replica in a different region.  The replication is asynchronous.  It works in vcore and premium but not in basic/standard (as those two are not using the same file storage mechanism underneath).  One small note:  There is no technical requirement to set up Active Geo DR to a different region - you can set it up in the same region (though it does not provide DR protection then)